# Flutter vlc player crashes app after going back

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-video-player

I have added flutter vlc player to my app. when i go back from vlc player page, the app suddenly crashes.

i have tried direct example from pub.dev to try it out, but it also results into same.
This is my Error

```
D/apitrace(22547): apitrace: warning: caught signal 6
D/apitrace(22547): call flush from exceptionCallback
F/libc    (22547): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 23200 
(AWindowHandler), pid 22547 (.webyte.vidflix)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'OPPO/CPH2015/OP4C7D:9/PPR1.180610.011/1640680627:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
pid: 22547, tid: 23200, name: AWindowHandler  >>> com.webyte.vidflix <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'java_vm_ext.cc:542] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI GetJavaVM called with pending exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Error during detachFromGLContext (see logcat for details)'
```

here ismy code

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _videoPlayerController = VlcPlayerController.network(
      'https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4',
      hwAcc: HwAcc.full,
      autoPlay: true,
      options: VlcPlayerOptions(),
    )..initialize();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() async {
    super.dispose();
    await _videoPlayerController!.stopRendererScanning();
    await _videoPlayerController!.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: Are you disposing of the controller correctly? As per [the documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_vlc_player), it is necessary to call `_videoPlayerController.stopRendererScanning()` and `_videoPlayerController.dispose()`

Comment: i am calling it. but it still shows error.

Answer (score 0):

Stop the video before disposing.

```
 @override
  void dispose() async {
    super.dispose();
    await _videoPlayerController!.stop();
    await _videoPlayerController!.stopRendererScanning();
    await _videoPlayerController!.dispose();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1

```
@override  
void deactivate() async {
  await _videoPlayerController!.stop();
  super.deactivate();
}
```

Solution 2

change hardware option from HwAcc.full to HwAcc.disabled